# Passing an image from one activity to other activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to pass an image which is from the mobile media. I am able to get the image from the media but I need to send that image to the next activity. How can I send that?

And can anyone give me the sample code to make the image to base64 string and vice versa in android.

Please help me I am stuck with this for two days...

Thanks in advance...

sita.

Comment: Bad assumption sita. Is it too tough to cache the image and pass the filename to the next activity ? That is so much more efficient than using putParcelable().

Answer (score 2):

for this first u save that image in one file and in other activity take that image from that file

Comment: (-1) an overhead. There is a built-in mechanism of passing data between activities. See my answer.

Comment: @Vlad not really [read this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/11f252430b34f4b8/49cfea00e229d537?show_docid=49cfea00e229d537). While it possible its not recommended. It all depends on the size of the image.

Comment: +1 to counteract the -1. Save to file is far better than transferring in a bundle.

Comment: the image is form the mobile media stores....i need to get the image form the mobile cam album dinamicaly

Answer (score 0):

To pass the data between two activities:

```
bytes[] imgs = ... // your image
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("img", imgs);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in YourActivity:

```
bytes[] receiver = getIntent().getExtra("imgs");
```

Comment: actually the requirement is user will select the image from his memory card or mobile media storage and will make use of the image in some other form.....i got the image data.getdata(); from onActivityResult()....now i need to get the path of that image and  i need to set on the image in next activity....

Answer (score 0):

You can use like:

I suppose that: send image to Activity B from A

Actvity: A

```
  Intent i = new Intent(A.this,B.class);

  i.putExtra("image_send",bitmap)
  //with bitmap is image that you want to send.
  startActivity(i);
```

Activity B:

```
  //receive image
  Bitmap b = (Bitmap) getIntent().ParcelableExtra("image_send")
```