# Pass crop bitmap to other activity

Tags: android

I'm currently creating a simple photo editor. Is it possible to pass crop bitmap to the other activity? I'd like some tutorials.

Comment: What did you try ? It should be simple enough to pass it in a bundle if it's not too big. If big then use @Emmanuel technique.

Comment: Also read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895404/passing-an-image-from-one-activity-to-other-activity?rq=1. Not exactly a duplicate, but close to..

Comment: The bitmap was showing in the crop intent but when I save it it doesnt show in the next activity. What seems to be the problem? Sorry for my question. Im just new with this.

Comment: Not clear enough, you should show some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the `Bitmap` to a specified path. Then send the path to the `Bitmap` via an `Intent`.

Comment: Ive read some tutorials they use URI. Is it easier to use intent?

Comment: The URI specifies the path to the saved `Bitmap`. The `Intent` is used to start a new `Activity` and you are given the option of passing extras to it. In your case you can use a simple `String` that contains the path to your `Bitmap`.